# Why does the view get two different Model.Id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to understand the basics of MVC. I implemented a simple CRUD that works just fine, but I don't understand how the "Update" part works.

My model class is very simple :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the two controller actions that I use for updating :

```
//id is passed through the url (action/controller/id)
public ActionResult UpdateUser(int id)
    {
        Models.User userToUpdate = Data_Services.DataServices.GetUserById(id);
        return View(userToUpdate);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Updateuser(Models.User userToUpdate)
    {
        Data_Services.DataServices.UpdateUser(userToUpdate);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The `DataServices` class performs some basic database stuff. Now here is the thing : I made a mistake in `DataServices.GetUserById`, it returns a User with correct name and email, **but Id = 0**.

Nonetheless, **when the form is posted back, the model passed to the controller has the correct Id!**
It is contained in a hidden field. But where does it come from?

Here is part of the View:

```
@model CRUD_MVC.Models.User
*...*
<p>id of the user in Model : @Model.Id</ p>   *shows 0*
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)   *contains the correct Id!*
```

So my question is : **why are there different values in the two Model.Id? And where does the "real" Id come from, since the only thing that was passed to the view is 0?**

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you. I really tried to search, but I didn't know how to phrase the question...

Comment: No problem, happy to be of help.